# Tensorflow concat 2D dimension Tensor to a 3D dimension tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is rather a simple question. I've a tensor in 3D shape. Lets say it is `[2,2,3]`. I've another tensor in 2D shape `[2,2]`. But the first 2 dimensions of both the elements are matching. I want to `concat` them such that the 2D tensor is added to the 3D tensor in the third dimension. i.e
`[2,2,4]`.

I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried using `tf.concat` and `tf.stack` but that requires both the tensors to be the same rank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to convert the smaller tensor to the correct rank, followed by [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat):

```
tensor_3d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 2, 3])
tensor_2d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 2])

tensor_2d_as_3d = tf.expand_dims(tensor_2d, 2)  # shape: [2, 2, 1]

result = tf.concat([tensor_3d, tensor_2d_as_3d], 2)  # shape: [2, 2, 4]
```